# Instead of sending a set of random values, send a key for a PRF

Tags: hash, protocol-design, provable-security, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

Some Protocols require one party to send $n$ random challenges (or random values) to another party. For communication efficiency purpose, one can pick a random key for a pseudorandom function, and send only the key to the other party, instead. Given the key and the function, the recipient can generate $n$ (pseudorandom) values locally.

In [here](https://hovav.net/ucsd/dist/verstore.pdf) (on page 5) it's stated that we cannot prove it in the standard model but can we can do it in  random oracle model. However, in [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-70290-2_1.pdf) (on page 12-13) it is said we can use *block cipher in the counter mode* to do that. So it's a bit confusing.

**Question**: Why cannot we use standard primitives and assumptions to construct a provably secure scheme described above?

Comment: The outputs of a prf are indistinguishable from random *if you do not know the key*. Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 3):

It depends very much on what you require from the random values that are sent. If they need to be random (pseudorandom) then sending the key is a problem. However, if you just need unpredictability, then this may be enough. Bottom line, there is no one answer. It depends on the protocol and requirements, and often is only apparent when doing a formal security proof.